# OpenVPN Bridged client can't see rest of subnet

Tags: networking, openvpn, bridge

I've got an OpenVPN setup using bridging mode, as I need both clients and computers on the network to be on the same subnet.

My server has eth0 and tap0 bridged into br0. The server can ping both sides.
The OpenVPN server config uses the `server-bridge` directive to allow clients to get their own IP from the network's DHCP server. IP forwarding is enabled, and `iptables` has no rules, and default `ACCEPT`.

Clients can connect fine, but only broadcast traffic seems to cross the bridge. I cannot get a DHCP lease over the tunnel, though I can see from `tcpdump` that the request is sent over the tunnel, and even the DHCP server sees the request and sends a reply, but it never reaches the client.

I can also see ARP and other broadcast traffic over the tunnel, but I can't actually resolve an IP using `arping`. ARP requests are sent and received, but responses are never received by the client.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I prefer to use `tap` layer 2 VPN interfaces for bridged VPNs. I don't even know if L3 `tun` interfaces work with bridging..

Comment: Thanks, I made a typo there. `tun` definitely doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having this issue and are running the server from a VM in ESXi, the problem is that ESXi doesn't allow promiscuous network interfaces by default.

To solve this, go into vSphere client, then Configuration -> Networking -> Properties -> Edit -> Security ->change Promiscuous Mode to Accept.